# Get thumbnails with array sizes parameter

Tags: plugin-development, post-thumbnails, thumbnails

I am trying to get both `full` and `thumbnail` images from post with `wp_get_attachment_image_url`:

```
wp_get_attachment_image_url( get_the_ID(), array('thumbnail, full'));
```

I know that by default `size` is `thumbnail` and I read from documentation that I can pass and array of sizes, but with above example, I am getting an error:

> A non-numeric value encountered

The documentation is not clear about how to pass an array of sizes as parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You’re almost correct.

You really can pass an array as size parameter for that function, but...

> **$size** (string|array) (Optional) Image size to retrieve. Accepts any
>   valid image size, or an array of width and height values in pixels (in
>   that order). Default value: 'thumbnail'

So you can’t use it in the way you wanted to...

You have to pass name of the size or an array that will define the size in pixels (width and height).

You can get only one size with one call of that function (as it returns only one value - url of image in given size).

But that’s not a problem, just call it twice:

```
$thumb_url = wp_get_attachment_image_url( get_the_ID(), 'thumbnail');
$full_url = wp_get_attachment_image_url( get_the_ID(), 'full');
```

Comment: Thanks, I just want to prevent this twice :). I will use that for now and may be custom query, later